# Glue-Job to convert CSV events into Parquet

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-athena

Basically, I have csv_events in my S3_bucket(s3://csv_events/user=111/year=2020/month=07/no.of.csv files). I want to convert these events into parquet format and want to store the results into another S3_bucket(s3://parquet_events/user=111/year=2020/month=07/parquet_files).

**My Approach:**
First, i created a glue-crawler to crawl csv_events and created a athena_table(csv_events_table).  Then Created a Glue-job, which will take csv_events_table as a input and convert those events into parquet and stored the results into S3. Finally, created another table for this parquet_events(parquet_events_table).

**My approach is similar to this:** https://www.powerupcloud.com/how-to-convert-historical-data-into-parquet-format-with-date-partitioning/

it is working fine, but i end up with having two athena_tables(csv_events_table,parquet_events_table).

**Is there any way to directly access s3 data into glue job and convert it into parquet format? So that i will have only one athena_table(parquet_events_table)**

Please let me know.

Regards
-Siva

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you can create the spark session (my preference) or you can use glue context to read data from s3 directly

```
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

df = spark.read.csv(s3path)
```

Comment: Hi shubham, 

It may work if we have one csv file, But i have a no of csv file with partitions as well.

Can you please explain how can i do that?

Comment: Provide the path to the table folder only... If your path is  `s3://bucket/table/partition/a.csv`  pass only `s3://bucket/table` and spark will populate allbpartition details for u

Comment: Hi shubham, it is working.

I have another issue. whenever i want to access s3_data directly in glue_job, with the help of ```spark.read.csv(s3path)``` i can achieve the result. But glue_job  ```job_bookmark_option``` is not working(incremental_processing is not possible ).  I didn't find much information in the documenation and online.

Can you help me how i can achieve this.

Comment: Job bookmarks are not available when you make use of data frames. They are only available while using Dynamic Frames. Even so, you need to make sure you have the transformation contexts and make sure you exit using the job.commit() in order for the state to be saved. Glue Dynamic frames can also access s3 directly using from_options.  You can find this here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader-from_options

Comment: Hi Eman,

Thanks for your suggestion.

Basically i followed your aproach and wrote a glue job using data_frames which will directly access s3_data.

I have another issue here, whenever glue_job is writing parquet files in s3, it is writing them like this `user_id=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION/year=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION/month=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION/no.parquet_files`.

if you see above path, glue job is writing `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION` instead of actual pratiton value.

Can you please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Hey check if you are having null values for your partition column

Comment: Also accept and upvote if this helps and open a different question with details. thanks :)

Comment: Hi shubham,

I checked it, my dataset doesn't have any null values in the partition column.